# Does Mule support password grant type for OAuth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, mule

I looked at mule-oauth2.xsd and found only client credentials and authorization grant type elements.  However, looking at the oauth2-provider:config it can be configured as supportedGrantTypes="RESOURCE_OWNER_PASSWORD_CREDENTIALS". If it does support resource owner password credentials, how can I configure an oauth2-client to retrieve a token? I am looking at retrieving a token from the OAuth2 provider using the oauth2:client. Here is an example of what I'm referring to, however, I want to achieve this for password.

```
 <http:request-config name="requestConfigWithOAuth">
    <oauth2:client-credentials-grant-type
            clientId="${client.id}"
            clientSecret="${client.secret}"
            tokenManager-ref="tokenManagerConfig">
        <oauth2:token-request tokenUrl="${token.url}"/>
    </oauth2:client-credentials-grant-type>
</http:request-config>
```

Comment: So how exactly did you manage to do it ? I can't find any answer online and it doesn't seem like mule 4 implemented password authentication :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Breen-
yes Mule provides Password Grant type. I recently configured for my APIs. In API management console, when you generate a client application , it provides an option for different grant types to select which is out of the box from MULE. you do not have to do any set up for this. It is through API management console on Anypoint platform. 
Let me know if any question.

Comment: For oauth2:client? I saw you could for the oauth2:provider but not for the client. Could you share your configuration  without the credentials of course? Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your response, I did solve this problem a long ago. I found out it does.

Answer (score 0):

MuleSoft supports the following authentication in Mule 3.8 client apps:

Basic Authentication

NTLM Authentication

Digest Authentication

OAuth2 - Authorization Code

OAuth2 - Client Credentials

[See the docs](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/authentication-in-http-requests#oauth2-client-credentials).

Comment: That's exactly what I am stating there is no OAuth2 support for RESOURCE OWNER PASSWORD grant type, there is only client support for credentials and authorization code i.e. last 2 in your list.

Comment: Asking the Eng why it's supported in the provider and not the client.

Comment: The Eng who wrote the code is on vacation so we can't answer yet. In the meantime, an enhancement request is being opened for the Mule 3.8 client to support all grant types supported by the 3.8 provider.

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately, the company I work at will be not be upgrading just yet.